# LiveData onChanged null results

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, dao, android-room

*EventDao*

```
@Dao
public interface EventDao {    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date_start = :date")
    LiveData<List<EventPatientLocation>> test(Date date);
}
```

*EventRepository*

```
public class EventRepository {
    private EventDao eventDao;

    public EventRepository(Application application) {
        MyDatabase db = MyDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        eventDao = db.eventDao();
    }

    public LiveData<List<EventPatientLocation>> test(Date date) {
        return eventDao.test(date);
    }
```

*EventViewModel*

```
public class EventViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private EventRepository repository;

    public EventViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new EventRepository(application);
    }

    public LiveData<List<EventPatientLocation>> test(Date date) {
        return repository.test(date);
    }
}
```

*Fragment (onActivityCreated)*

```
eventViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(EventViewModel.class);

LiveData<List<EventPatientLocation>> testEvent = eventViewModel.test(new Date());

testEvent.observe(activity, events -> {
    // events is always null!
});
```

Despite the onChanged callback on fragment is called multiple times, the events list is always null...I know for sure that in database there are candidate rows for the query, so where am I doing wrong? Help please...

Comment: I think the problem here is `new Date()` because it returns the current timestamp. Which will not likely satisfied this `date_start = :date` cuz your records have older dates (please consider that it might be comparing the hours, min and seconds too).

Comment: You'll surely right! How can I pass that to the query? Should I erase time?

Comment: I think just try using something like `date_start <= :date` or `date_start >= :date`.

Comment: Ok, I've erased (set to 00:00:00) the date time and changed the query to date_start >= :date as suggested by @Enzokie. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad you found a solution that suits your usecase!